# @RequestParam annotation at class level not working as expected

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

This is the controller:

```java
        package com.spring.controller;

        import java.util.Arrays;
        import java.util.List;

        import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

        import org.jboss.logging.annotations.Param;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
        import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

        import com.spring.DAO.CountryDAO;
        import com.spring.DAO.HospitalDAO;
        import com.spring.DAO.HospitalSpecialityDAO;
        import com.spring.DAO.SpecialityDAO;
        import com.spring.VO.HospitalSpecialityVO;
        import com.spring.VO.HospitalVO;
        import com.spring.VO.SpecialityVO;

        @Controller
        @RequestMapping("/admin")
        public class HospitalController {

            @Autowired
            CountryDAO country;
            @Autowired
            HospitalDAO hospital;
            @Autowired
            SpecialityDAO Speciality;
            @Autowired
            HospitalSpecialityDAO hospitalSpeciality;

    @RequestMapping("/addHospital.html")
    public ModelAndView addHospital(HttpSession session) throws Exception {
      List<Object> list = this.country.getCountry();
      session.setAttribute("list", list);
      List<Object> slist = this.Speciality.getSpeciality();
      session.setAttribute("slist", slist);
      return new ModelAndView("admin/addHospital",
            "insertHospitalSpeciality", new HospitalSpecialityVO());

    }
   }
```

And this is the URL which I want to map:

```
/projectname/admin/addHospital.html
```

This is the `web.xml` file:

```xml
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
                version="2.5">

                <servlet>
                    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>

                    <servlet-class>
                    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
                    </servlet-class>
                    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
                </servlet>

                <servlet-mapping>
                    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
                    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
                </servlet-mapping>

            <listener>
            <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
            </listener>
            <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
            </context-param>
            <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
            </filter-class>
            </filter>
            <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            </filter-mapping>


            </web-app>
```

`spring-servlet.xml` file:

```xml
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
                xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
                xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  

                <context:component-scan  base-package="com.spring" /> 



                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
                    <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/view/" />  
                    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
                </bean>  
                <bean id="multipartResolver"
                    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

                     <!-- setting maximum upload size -->
                    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000" />

                </bean>
                <!-- <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
                    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
                    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/healthanalytics"/>
                    <property name="username" value="root"/>
                    <property name="password" value="root"/>
                </bean> -->

                <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
                    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

                     <property name="annotatedClasses">
                        <list>
                            <value>com.spring.VO.CityVO</value>
                            <value>com.spring.VO.ComplainVO</value>
                            <value>com.spring.VO.CountryVO</value>
                            <value>com.spring.VO.DiseaseVO</value>
                            <value>com.spring.VO.DoctorVO</value>
                            <value>com.spring.VO.FeedbackVO</value>
                            <value>com.spring.VO.HospitalVO</value>
                            <value>com.spring.VO.MedicineVO</value>
                            <value>com.spring.VO.PatientVO</value>
                            <value>com.spring.VO.StateVO</value>
                            <value>com.spring.VO.SpecialityVO</value>
                            <value>com.spring.VO.SymptomVO</value>
                            <value>com.spring.VO.HospitalSpecialityVO</value>
                            <value>com.spring.VO.DoctorSpecialityVO</value>
                            <value>com.spring.VO.DoctorHospitalVO</value>
                            <value>com.spring.VO.RegistrationVO</value>
                            <value>com.spring.VO.LoginVO</value>




                            <!-- <value>com.malhar.model.Login</value> -->
                        </list>
                    </property>
                    <property name="hibernateProperties">
                        <props>
                            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_load_trans">true</prop>
                        </props>
                    </property>
                </bean>      

            </beans>
```

But when I call the following url:

```
http://localhost:8080/health/admin/addHospital.html
```

I get:

> HTTP Status 404 - /health/admin/WEB-INF/view/admin/addHospital.jsp

Here `health` is the project name.

I am not able to figure out that while getting the result why it is trying to put `admin` before `WEB-INF` as shown in error.

Why can't it just get result from `/health/WEB-INF/view/admin/addHospital.jsp`?

Also if anyone can provide any alternate solution to this it would be much helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In your view resolver configuration, put `/` before `WEB-INF/view/` and for CSS and JavaScript resources use `mvc:resources` tag to configure resource location and in JSP import them using `c:url`.

Comment: Thanks. yeah it worked. actually the i changed the folder structure a bit. First  it was WebContent/resorces then i changed to WebContent/admin/resources and it worked. chrome's developer mode helped to figure it out and properly structure the folder.